# upgrade from angular 4 to 6 for http giving error map does not exists

Tags: angular

I have upgraded from angular 4 to 6 and have changed the http library to httpClient. I am getting error with the http method saying map does not exist. Could somebody tell me what the problem is

```
export class LocalisationProxy {
    constructor(private _nghttp: HttpClient,
                private _phttp: ProxyHttp) { } 


    getLatestTranslationFilesAndMerge(cultureId: number): Observable<ApiResult<any>> {
        return this._nghttp.get(`/platform/localisation/${cultureId}`, null||{})
                    .map(ret => ({ data: ret.json(), originalResponse: ret}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably, in newest version of RxJs you have to use operators in pipable way. No more operators based on prototypes.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Answer (score 4):

With rxjs 6 now is used pipable operators.

```
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

    getLatestTranslationFilesAndMerge(cultureId: number): Observable<ApiResult<any>> {
         return this._nghttp.get(`/platform/localisation/${cultureId}`,null||{})
            .pipe(map((ret=>({ data: ret.json(), originalResponse: ret})));
        }
    }
```

Because you are using the httpClient by default it is converted to json so your map is unecessary.

```
getLatestTranslationFilesAndMerge(cultureId: number): Observable<Something> {
         return this._nghttp.get<Something>(`/platform/localisation/${cultureId}`);
        }
    }
```

Comment: getting property usignal is missing in the type Observable<ApiResult<any>>

Comment: I changed it to this but still same error getLatestTranslationFilesAndMerge(cultureId: number): Observable<ApiResult<any>> {
         return this._nghttp.get<ApiResult<any>>(`/platform/localisation/${cultureId}`);
        }
    }

Comment: it also gives error that Observable<ApiResult<any>> is not assignable to Observable<ApiResult<any>>

Answer (score 1):

Please use RxJS-compact while upgrading to angular 6

just install rxjs-compat by typing in terminal:

`npm install --save rxjs-compat`

then import :

`import 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: Map is still supported operator in RxJs. The only difference is it's not extending observable prototype but is encapsulated into some pure (pipable) function.